# For loop in php code needs an explanation

Tags: php, html, for-loop, associative-array

```
<!-- 1- create a new file called lab3.php
           2- add the HTML skeleton code and give its title “Lab Week 3”
           3- open up an php scope
           4- Create an associative array listing favourite subjects. (example: math, english, science and grade for each A+ B+ C-  )
           5- print out for grade english subject
           6- using a for loop print all the items in the array
           --> 
   >
```

```
<?php

//Code for associative array

        //data for associated array
        $subjects = [
        "math" => "A+",
        "english" => "B+",
        "science" => "C-",
        
        ]
        
        <br>
    

// Code to print out english grade

        //print out for english grade
        
        echo "My grade in english class is" . $subjects["english"];
        
        <br>
   
// This is my for loop section. If anyone could help me figure this out I'd be greatly appreciated.

        //print out all the items in the array using for loop
        
        for ($x=0; <= 2){
        echo  "$subjects[$x]";
        }
        
        ?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for ($x = 0; $x <= 2; ++$x)` ?

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the items in your array use `foreach` instead:

```
foreach ($subjects as $subject => $grade) {
echo 'My grade in '.$subject. ' is '. $grade . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**BTW**: 1. Don't forget to remove `<br>` tags in your php code.

2. You cannot use `for` loop here, since your array does not have numeric array keys, and if you run `for` loop in the way you showed in your code, you will get `undefined array key` warnings.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RczNCsIwEATge55iCIUoal@gVlERPCj2LiIxXZuItqGpBxGfPdb@6N72Y2astt5P51ZbFrjH@UqqcohxYKiP32WlOeIZ@GLEx61Rnt2M63j5Y6cM5YpaXk1qPkaMsUtRklQag/@6dOifbzjISpnSEK9mh5QuIHZPNAqTQ4R9OoSAcTV0HYRINslpvd9G7O39Bw)